# magento upgrade 1.12.0.2 to 1.13.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.13

I am having a serious issue while upgrading from Magento EE 1.12.0.2 to 1.13.0.2.
After the upgrade when I run `php -f shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php` script as suggested in upgrade doc, I am facing the error below:

Fatal error:

> Uncaught exception 'Enterprise_Index_Model_Action_Exception' with
> message 'No table has been specified for the FROM clause' in
> /var/www/app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Url/Rewrite/Category/Refresh.php:165

Stack trace:

> #0 /var/www/app/code/core/Enterprise/Mview/Model/Client.php(109): Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Index_Action_Url_Rewrite_Category_Refresh->execute()
>
> #1 /var/www/shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php(75): Enterprise_Mview_Model_Client->execute('enterprise_cata...')
>
> #2 {main}   thrown in /var/www/app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Url/Rewrite/Category/Refresh.php
> on line 165

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?